# Extract a string array from an object in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, object, extract

It's been a while since I studied programming and I'm struggling with this.

I receive from a web service a bunch of info, which I save on an object, then after using the reflection method I get arrays, so I'm still stuck on having arrays inside an object.

I just cant remember how to convert the arrays inside of the object to string arrays, can someone help me out?

```
object information = new object();
string propName="members";
information=sinos1.Info(Convert.ToInt32(edo),Convert.ToInt32(anio),Convert.ToInt64(familia));
Object value = GetPropValue( information, propName);
```

`information` is the object that receives the info from the web service and `value` is the object that receives the info after the reflection which code is:

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
     return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to probe the object for interfaces.

```
object value = GetPropValue(information, propName);

if(value is IEnumerable)
{
    var array = value as IEnumerable;
    foreach(object obj in array)
    {

    }
}
```

Further you can use `Type.GetTypeCode` on the `obj` for handling value types.

Comment: I don't know if this may help out to help read whats on value, while debugging, this is what value type changes from object to:
object {ScanIt.sinos2.Sinos_Integrante[]}
this happens after reflection